# return Text.search(/[^a-zA-Z]+/) === -1?

Tags: javascript

What would return if found any special character in the given `text value`  and what if not ?

`return Text.search(/[^a-zA-Z]+/) === -1`

Comment: Try it, the same way we will have to try it for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return Text.search(/[^a-zA-Z]+/) === -1`

should be return: **false**

you can try with this: http://jsfiddle.net/XNJxT/786/

and I though that's would be **false** if it found any special characters

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are looking for a non-English character (case insensitive) in the string. If such a character is encountered it would return false. You are inverting the set of characters `[a-zA-Z]` so it is looking for any other character.

Answer (score -1):

it's a regular expression. "^" means start with , "a-zA-Z" means letters a to z ignore case, "+" means one or more.

Comment: Not quite true: the `^` is inside a char-class (`[^]`), in which case it means _"anything except"_. Also, this isn't what is being asked

Comment: you are right. the ^ is inside a char-class ([^]), in which case it means "anything except".